# How to append the value from <v-select> when value changed to the label of it's respective <v-file-input> | Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

i'm a beginner here.  I'm creating a vuefity form with three `<v-file-input>` each having one `<v-select>` option retrospectively.
i would like to append the value from `<v-select>` when value changed to the label of it's respective `<v-file-input>`.

Please help me, solve this problem. CodePen : https://codepen.io/jx46/full/pooMwQp

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: ['one', 'two', 'three']
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-container>

          <v-form>
            <v-row>
              <v-col>
                <v-select :items="items" label="Standard"></v-select>
              </v-col>
              <v-col>
                <v-file-input label="File input"></v-file-input>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>

            <v-row>
              <v-col>
                <v-select :items="items" label="Standard"></v-select>
              </v-col>
              <v-col>
                <v-file-input label="File input"></v-file-input>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>

            <v-row>
              <v-col>
                <v-select :items="items" label="Standard"></v-select>
              </v-col>
              <v-col>
                <v-file-input label="File input"></v-file-input>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>

          </v-form>

        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define `data` for each pair (`v-select`- `v-input`). Then bind it as `v-model` and `:label`.

Template:

```html
<v-select
   v-model="firstSelectValue"                   
   :items="items"
   label="Standard"
></v-select>
```

```html
<v-file-input :label="firstSelectValue"></v-file-input>
```

JS:

```js
data: () => ({
   items: ['one','two','three'],
   firstSelectValue: 'File input',
   secondSelectValue: 'File input',
   thirdSelectValue: 'File input',
})
```

Changed Codepen: https://codepen.io/RobbyFront/pen/eYYqEBx

Comment: What if the `<v-select>` items data is an object with text and value. Then how to append the `<v-file-input>` label with the selected text-value ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what are you mention with "object with text and value". Can you provide an example?

Comment: the data passed to the `<v-select :items="item">` items is an javascript Object. ```items: [
      {text: "One", value : '1'},
      {text: "Two", value : '2'},
      {text: "Three", value : '3'},
    ] ```

Comment: I understand you, but you have to create another question at SO, because it's not same as original one.